# How to delete user message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

how can I delete a message in discord.py if it contains a word from a word list? I have already tried several methods, some gave an error and some did not but the messages were not deleted.
Maybe I have set something wrong in discord? I have turned on manage messages.

Comment: what did you try? You should show it in question. And you should show full error messages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code loops through every word you have in a list `badwords` and searches for them in the message content. If it finds a word that matches the word from the list it deletes it. I used [`lower()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lower) to make sure it doesn't matter how you write your message (*badword, BADWORD, BAdWoRd etc.*).

```py
badwords = ["badword", "another word", "example"]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    msg = message.content

    for x in badwords:
        if x in msg.lower():
            await message.delete()
            break

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

**I'm also pretty sure you have to enable [`intents.messages`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Intents) to make it work.**

Comment: Thanks, i will try this

Comment: Man thanks much much it works perfectly! Much much thanks to you!